# MySQL 5.7.10 Simple Query Slower than 5.6.35

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-5.6

I've copied a database from 5.6.35 to 5.7.10, both are MYSQL Community Server versions and for some reason my query is running really really slow. It is a InnoDB database.

5.6 is my development server.

- Windows Server Standard SP2
- 32BIT
- 4GB Ram

5.7 is my production server

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1
- 64BIT
- 24GB Ram

It is not a complicated query by any stretch.

```
SELECT t.*
,(SELECT `name` FROM users u1 WHERE u1.id = t.addedby) AS addebyname
,(SELECT `name` FROM users u2 WHERE u2.id = t.modifiedby) AS modifiedbyname
,(SELECT `title` FROM tasks_groups tg WHERE tg.id = t.groupid) AS grouptitle
,(
CASE
    WHEN t.active=0 THEN CONCAT(t.title,' (Inactive)')
    ELSE t.title
    END
) AS combo
,(SELECT
    IFNULL(SUM(ts.worked),0)
    FROM timesheet ts
    WHERE ts.taskid=t.id
) AS totaltaskhours
FROM tasks t
```

- 5.6 takes 0.468 secs to return 58 records
- 7.5 takes 89.922 secs to return 58 records

If I remove the (SELECT IFNULL...) part of the query then it runs really fast, so not sure why that is slowing the query down on 5.7.  I have all indexes set between the various tables. Timesheet only has 238837 rows so not even that big.

[image]

Bit lost as to the reason for this...

Here is the EXPLAIN results, not really sure what it all means..

5.6
[image]

5.7
[image]

Comment: Have you compared the `Explain` results for both the different runs ?

Comment: I hadn't but I've added that now, not 100% what they mean though, never really encountered an issue like this before

Comment: It looks like you have significantly more data (atleast twice) in your production server (by looking at second row of your explain statement results).

Comment: Just ran a SELECT COUNT(*)  from timesheet
5.6 = 231740
5.7 = 232243

so not that much difference. So not sure why there is a big difference in the EXPLAIN

Comment: 5.7 is not able to use `idx_taskid` index. Also, your query is not simple (as it seems to you). There are too many subqueries in it. You may possible consider rewriting them using joins, etc.

Comment: Could you explain how I could get 5.7 to use that index. I have tried the query with joins and on 5.6 makes very little difference in the time.  Still takes 0.469 seconds to return the 58 rows

Comment: Try adding this at end: `FROM tasks t USE INDEX (idx_taskid)` instead of `FROM tasks t`

Comment: That index doesn't exist on the task table, it's on the timesheet one

Comment: Then, you can add the `use index` line near `FROM timesheet ts`

Comment: Sorry should have said I tried that and made difference at all

Comment: Try `force index` instead of `use index`. How many timesheets does a task have? MySQL (actually both versions) seems to assume that every value for task_id in timesheet is basically the same (the "1" in the penultimate column in your image), although an execution time of 0.468 seem to indicate otherwise. Are there actually timesheets without a task?

Comment: force index, certainly sped things up, now returning rows in 3.500 secs.  Nope all timesheet entries have a task.  Why am I having to force the use of the index, when it is already there on the table and I don't have to do this on 5.6?

Answer (score 0):

Whoever installed MySQL Server hadn't bothered to set the **innodb_buffer_pool_size** in the INI file to a good size.  Was really low 8M on a 24GB server, increased the size and now everything is running as expected.  Thanks for everyone's suggestions